# How to map nested array items with N1QL?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have documents in a bucket called `blocks` in the following format:

```
{
  "random_field": 1,
  "transactions": [{
    "id": "CCCCC",
    "inputs": [{
      "tx_id": "AAAAA",
      "index": 0
    },{
      "tx_id": "BBBBB",
      "index": 1
    }]
  }]
}

{
  "transactions": [{
    "id": "AAAAA",
    "outputs": [{
      "field1": "value123",
      "field2": "value456"
    },{
      "field1": "ignore",
      "field2": "ignore"
    }]
  }]
}

{
  "transactions": [{
    "id": "BBBBB",
    "outputs": [{
      "field1": "ignored",
      "field2": "ignored"
    },{
      "field1": "value999",
      "field2": "value888"
    }]
  }]
}
```

and I need to map the `inputs` from the first document to the corresponding outputs of the second and third documents. The way to do it manually is to, for each input, find a transaction with `id` equal to the input's `tx_id`, and then get the item from the `outputs` array based on the `index` of the input. To exemplify, this is the object I would like to return in this scenario:

```
{
  "random_field": 1,
  "transactions": [{
    "id": "CCCCC",
    "inputs": [{
      "tx_id": "AAAAA",
      "index": 0,
      "output": {
        "field1": "value123",
        "field2": "value456"
      }
    },{
      "tx_id": "BBBBB",
      "index": 1,
      "output": {
        "field1": "value999",
        "field2": "value888"
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

I managed to come up with the following query:

```
SELECT b.random_field,
  b.transactions -- how to map this?
FROM blocks b
UNNEST b.transactions t
UNNEST t.inputs input
JOIN blocks `source` ON (ANY tx IN `source`.transactions SATISFIES tx.`id` = input.tx_id END)
UNNEST `source`.transactions source_tx
UNNEST source_tx.outputs o
WHERE (ANY tx IN b.transactions SATISFIES tx.`id` = 'AAAAA' END) LIMIT 1;
```

I suppose there should be a way to map `b.transactions.inputs` by using `source_tx.outputs`, but I couldn't find how.

I came across this other answer, but I don't really understand how it applies to my scenario. Maybe it does, but I am very new to Couchbase, so I am very much lost: [How to map array values in one document to another and display in result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731985/how-to-map-array-values-in-one-document-to-another-and-display-in-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want inline some other document into current document using condition.

Instead  of JOINs+ GROUPS use subquery expressions + correlated subqueries. (b.*, "abc" AS transactions, selects all fields of b and adds transactions (if already exist overwrite else adds)

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON blocks (ALL ARRAY FOR ot.id FOR ot IN transactions END);

SELECT b.*,
       (SELECT t.*,
               (SELECT i.*,
                       (SELECT RAW ot
                        FROM blocks AS o
                        UNNEST o.transactions AS ot
                        UNNEST ot.outputs AS oto
                        WHERE i.tx_id = ot.id AND i.`index` = UNNEST_POS(oto))[0] AS output
                FROM t.`inputs` AS i) AS inputs
        FROM b.transactions AS t) AS transactions

FROM blocks AS b
WHERE ANY tx IN b.transactions SATISFIES tx.`inputs` IS NOT NULL END ;
```

OR

```
SELECT b.*,
       (SELECT t.*,
               (SELECT i.*,
                       (SELECT RAW ot.outputs[i.`index`] 
                        FROM blocks AS o
                        UNNEST o.transactions AS ot
                        WHERE i.tx_id = ot.id 
                        LIMIT 1)[0] AS output
                FROM t.`inputs` AS i) AS inputs
        FROM b.transactions AS t) AS transactions

FROM blocks AS b
WHERE ANY tx IN b.transactions SATISFIES tx.`inputs` IS NOT NULL END ;
```

Comment: I just had to also `UNNEST ot.outputs AS oto` and then `UNNEST_POS(oto)` instead of `UNNEST_POS(ot)`, but this answer is precisely what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: try SELECT RAW ot.outputs[i.`index`]   (remove UNNEST_POS)